# How to align two buttons next to each other?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm trying to put two floating button next to each other, I tried moving it with the design view but I can't move the button it goes back to the same spot.

I'm still confused about ConstraintLayout, Relativelayout and LinearLayout terms.

From what I've read LinearLayout is for Horizontal view so I tried changing my layout width and height to wrap content

Here is my current result

[image: result]

activity_main

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/resultText"
                    android:layout_width="363dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autoLink="all"
                    android:autofillHints="text edit"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_edit"
                    android:gravity="top"/>

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"/>

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/pdfBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Your button's are in LinearLayout which has `Vertical` Orientation, due to that your button's are stacked upon each other if you put them in a container and then align them next to each other then it will work.

For Explanation purpose i have used `Constraint Layout` the Constraint are set such as to constraint `Save Button` next to `pdf Button` and `pdf Button` to the end of the Parent.

#### Try Below Code

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/resultText"
                    android:layout_width="363dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autoLink="all"
                    android:autofillHints="text edit"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_edit"
                    android:gravity="top" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pdfBtn"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/pdfBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```